# JSON data extraction problem outside the switch and case. Stripe webhooks

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

The Stripe code of the webhooks extracts the data from the cases well, I need to store the product ID that the customer buys to know if they have a monthly or annual subscription, so I use this case "customer.subscription.created", So far so good the code creates two JSON for me and both with the correct information, but the problem comes when extracting the data from each one. For some reason the JSON of the customer data (the email) is extracted without problems and I can use it outside the switch to be able to insert it into the database, the problem comes with the product id of the customer.subscription.created case , when I define it outside the switch so that it can be inserted into the database, it gives me a PHP error telling me that it is not defined so it is never inserted, I do not understand why there is no problem for the value of email and the code for the product id is the same. On the other hand, if I execute the insertion of data inside the 'customer.subscription.created' case: there is no problem with it, product id, it is inserted into the database without problems, but of course the value of email is NO. I have tried everything: declare the variables outside the switch, change the order of execution, change the names of the variables and files, also that in both cases they put the data in a TXT and then read it, but nothing no matter how much I try it. try $product_id can't use it outside your switch

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require("../db-connection/db-connection.php");


// The library needs to be configured with your account's secret key.
// Ensure the key is kept out of any version control system you might be using.
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx');

// This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
}

$current_date = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$file_user_data_payment = 'data-pay/user_data_payment-' . $current_date . '.json';
$file_product_identifier_user_payment = 'data-pay/product_identifier_user_payment-' . $current_date . '.json';
$product_id = null;

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
  case 'payment_method.attached':
    $paymentMethod = $event->data->object;

    file_put_contents($file_user_data_payment, json_encode($paymentMethod) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $email = $paymentMethod->billing_details->email;
    break;

  case 'customer.subscription.created':
    $subscription = $event->data->object;

    file_put_contents($file_product_identifier_user_payment, json_encode($subscription) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $product_id = $subscription->plan->product;

    break;

  default:
    echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
}

if (isset($email)) {

  $verification_code = bin2hex(random_bytes(4));
  $insertPendingVerification = $CONEXION_BD->prepare("INSERT INTO users_pending_verification (email, product, verification_code) VALUES (:email, :product, :verification_code)");
  $insertPendingVerification->execute([
      ":email" => $email,
      ":product" => $product_id,
      ":verification_code" => $verification_code,
  ]);
  
  include('../send-email/email-send/verification-users.php');
}

http_response_code(200);
```